# Cant get $key from firebase- Angular http://localhost:4200/admin/products/undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, key

im working on an Angular project while following a course. I am trying to get the $key from my firebase, and use it in a route to redirect to an edit page, but I keep getting "undefined". I tried multiple solutions from here, but nothing works.

My product service .

```
create (product) {
return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
```

}

```
 getAll() {
return this.db.list('/products').valueChanges();
```

}

```
 get(productId) : Observable<any> { return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).snapshotChanges();
```

}

Where I want to use the $key.

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/',p.$key]"> Edit </a>
```

What I get in the browser:
http://localhost:4200/admin/products/undefined

Comment: Where is ‘p’ set..?

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
            <td> {{p.title}} </td>
            <td> {{p.price}} </td>
            <td>  </td>
            <td> 
                <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/',p.$key]"> Edit </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

Comment: Is p.title rendered?

Comment: Yes, i get price and title. The problem is only with $key,it comes as undefined.  I found something about it beeing a change in newer version , so this way doesnt work. And i dont know how to get the $key from the database now to show info about the products i have stored

Comment: So what do you get when you do {{ p | json }} ? Does it show the $key?

Comment: No,it doesn't.  I only get the data i have in the base {{key,values}},but i cant get the UID($key) of the product in firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
your best bet would be to try as an example like so - set your variable from firebase or firestore as products in your yourcomponent.component.html file:
<div *ngFor="let item of products | keyvalue">
 <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/',item.key]"> Edit </a>
</div>
```

the keyvalue pipe is made by angular specifically to segment values and keys and works well with ngfor.